# How can I used Mailgun within a PHP for loop?

Tags: php, mailgun

I have a list of emails stored in an array and I want to loop through that list and send out an email to each one with Mailgun.

Here is my script

```
$mgClient = new Mailgun('snipsnip');
$domain = "sandboxe08d52a4dcd247d7a31e3eb6e672ab03.mailgun.org";

$count = count($emails);
for($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++ ){
    $to = $emails[$i];
    $mgClient->sendMessage($domain, array(
    'from'    => 'Markus from StackOverflow <funnyemail@yes.com>',
    'to'      => $to,
    'subject' => 'Open This Email',
    'text'    => 'msg'
));
}
```

This is the error I get

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Mailgun\Connection\Exceptions\MissingRequiredParameters' with message 'The parameters passed to the API were invalid. Check your inputs!' in /home/content/63/11130563/html/sites/paidfor/includes/mailgun/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php:127 Stack trace: #0 /home/content/63/11130563/html/sites/paidfor/includes/mailgun/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(90): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->responseHandler(Object(Guzzle\Http\Message\Response)) #1 /home/content/63/11130563/html/sites/paidfor/includes/mailgun/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(80): Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('sandboxe08d52a4...', Array, Array) #2 /home/content/63/11130563/html/sites/paidfor/includes/mailgun/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(36): Mailgun\Mailgun->post('sandboxe08d52a4...', Array, Array) #3 /home/content/63/11130563/html/sites/paidfor/bag/success/index.php(21): Mailgun\Mailgun->sendMessage('sandboxe08d52a4...', A in /home/content/63/11130563/html/sites/paidfor/includes/mailgun/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php on line 127

Is this the right path for looping with Mailgun? Any tips?

contents of array $emails

```
Array
(
    [0] => tempemail@divc.com
    [1] => blue-flame@hotmail.com
)
```

update: I noticed that the script does not work with non gmail domains

Comment: placed at the beginning of this posted snippet, can you please post the output of `print_r($emails)`

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I added it to the bottom of my posting

Comment: just to clarify, you're saying this script does work for gmail domains?

Comment: @JeffPuckettII I stand corrected. the script does not work if the array has more than one email..regardless of extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have verified your code works as is with my mailgun account. The problem seems to be with authorized recipients with a sandbox domain.

> $domain = "sandboxe08d52a4dcd247d7a31e3eb6e672ab03.mailgun.org";

and since it is working when sending to one gmail address, I'm assuming that's your primary account on mailgun, which is authorized to receive from sandboxes by default.

In order to get other emails to receive from the sandbox, then you will have to add them **and *verify*** in the sandbox domain settings.

[image: Click on domain settings]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Comment: I figured it out! But following your steps helped me find the menu needed to get things squared away :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to answer my own question. I switched away from using the sandbox URL provided by mailgun and used a verified domain "APP Base URL" and it solved the issue.